# Anchor fails to activate in flexbox item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, anchor

I have a flex container holding multiple items.  I am setting the flex item class inside the anchor tag and trying to enable a link to work when a user clicks the anchored element.

The element is a 3 stage div... the first div is a circle with an icon, the "second" div (if you want to call it a second div...) loads the ::before psuedo element that loads some dimensionality to the circle.  and the third div is a text item that appears when the item is hovered.

The issue is that when you hover over the element i am not able to click the follow on link. My guess is the anchor is being covered by the divs.

I have attempted setting z-index's across elements but cant seem to get the anchor to expose itself

HTML:

```
 <div class="flex_row">

        <a class="flex_col" src="http://www.cnn.com">
            <div class="circle_shape">
                <i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i>
                <div class="circle_text">
                    <p>CNN IS A TERRIBLE NEW SOURCE!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>CNN SUCKS</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex_col{
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
}

.circle_shape {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding: 50% 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 120%, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #062745 100%);
  }

.circle_shape:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0px, #ffffff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58%);
    filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 2;
}


  .circle_shape:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  }

  .circle_shape img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

.circle_shape i{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 1px #fff, 
    0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.circle_shape h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    font-size: 1vw; 
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle_text{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0,51,102, 0.9);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.circle_text p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: calc(7px + .5vw);
    text-shadow: 
        0 0 1px #fff, 
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.circle_shape:hover .circle_text{
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/honeynutz/czq9y5fp/4/

I would expect the link in question to load cnn, but instead it does nothing.

Comment: Links don't have `src` they have `href` - `<a class="flex_col" src="http://www.cnn.com">`

Comment: Change `src` to `href`. Also this is not a place for political views.

Comment: Thanks all -- closing this out -- I cant believe i didnt catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple and I'm sure you'll kick yourself that you didn't spot it! I'm surprised it took me so long.

The issue is that you're using `src` on your `anchor` where you should be using `href`

More information on [HTML Links](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)